# AJAX loaded content and how to interact

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic-data

I have been learning more about AJAX using PHP and wanted to ask about the relationship of loaded content to the page itis loaded into.

I have been using the AJAX Pagination script v1.2.2 i found at "dynamicdrive".  I was able to properly implement the dynamic page load as expected and it works. The pages I load have images in them that i'd like to be able to add hyperlinks to. These links would change content on the original page with a similar function ( perhaps the ajax function .load() )

for some reason I can't seem to reference the objects on the original page fromt he loaded content to do any work. I noticed that when i "view source" on the page, I only see the original page and not the loaded content. I have been searching for anything I can use to determine how to interact between the original page and the loaded content. Is the "loaded" content a child page? i see a lot of references out there to iframes etc, but I know that this is not the method i'm using.

Any suggestions on the ralationship of these pages and how to interact betweent hem would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks,

Silver

Answer (score 0):

I can answer one part of your question - to view the source, try using Firefox extension - Developers tool bar, which allows you to view the 'Generated source'.

Or if you use element selector in any browser, it will show you the generated source.

Comment: well. can load the page seperately and view it's source, so that's not really a problem. I was more mentioning it because it may have been related to how these pages can or cant' interact.

Comment: Better is to use Firebug in which you can see the DOM of your page and you can manipulate it just like the script.

Comment: The good news? i can see the entire DOM tree with firebug which is what I had hoped for. The bad news? even if i build the ajax in the "loaded" section, it does not seem to recognize the DOM of the page that loaded it, so I can not load content into another DIV on the page using the AJAX included on the "loaded" content ... so, In a nutshell, still stuck where I was trying to figure out the relationship of the "loading page" and the "loaded" page